# Upgrade Nextcloud desktop client in Ubuntu to version 3.4.2, session closed, no way to start the session

Tags: upgrade, client, nextcloud

I upgrade Nextcloud desktop client in Ubuntu from version 2.6.2 to version  3.4.2. While everything worked well before, now I'm left with messages saying "session" is "closed" and there seems to be no way to connect as before, with commands on the right of the account details.

Comment: There is no Nextcloud 3.4.2 in Ubuntu. The current version of `nextcloud-desktop` is 3.2.3.

Comment: i read "Version 3.4.2 (KDE)" of "com.nextcloud.desktopclient.nextcloud" installed from flatpak yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place from where connect to the accounts has moved to a different place. In version 3.4.2 connecting to your account is done from the three little dots on the right of your account in the "main window" accessed from the icon in the top bar in Ubuntu.

[image: Nextcould client main window]